# What is this Op-Amp Configuration doing?

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal-processing, analysis

This Op-Amp Arrangement is part of an analog signal processing for a knock sensor of a combustion engine and I'm very curious about what this part actually does, as my google research didn't help me at all.

[image: Op-Amp-Curcuit]

Comment: The right most is a summing amplifier. And the left most seems an asymmetric clipping amplifier. The result is clipped signal plus original signal.

Comment: Why the heck would you do that?

Comment: Actually the signs are important here. Look at the 1st block: The result is 180° out of phase. So the 2nd block actually outputs the difference between original and clipped signal. If I'm wrong somebody correct me.

Comment: IC4 amp clamps on a negative input to about 0.7 V output and on a positive signal the output is -0.7 + gain set by R9/R8. IC5 sums signal with rectified signal providing a DC offset. Probably what you would do to offset an AC input signal into range for an ADC.

Comment: This is a fullwave rectifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a precision rectifier...

If A goes positive WRT B, then D1 is reverse biased, IC4 drives node 4 to -Vin * R9/R8.

If A goes negative WRT B then D1 is forward biased, D2 is reverse biased and node 4 is pulled to (virtual) ground by R9.

The next stage is a virtual earth summing amp, summing A with 2 * node 4 assuming all resistors are equal (inverting of course), Vout = -I*R13.

Lets see what currents we get into that virtual earth node:

I = Vin/R10 + Vn4/(R11||R12).

When input is negative, I = Vin/R10, because Vn4 = 0.
When input is positive, I = Vin/R10 + Vn4/(R11 || R12), but Vn4 = -Vin * R9/R8.

If we assume all resistors are equal then I(positive) = Vin/R -Vin * 2/R = -Vin/R.

Finally multiply I by R13 to get the output as a full wave rectified signal.

Thing thing is a precision full wave rectifier.

Comment: So basically: uout = - |uin| if all resistors are equal?

Comment: Or vout = - | vin | as you would probably say.

Answer (score 9):

It's a precision full wave rectifier. Try searching on google for it using those words. Here's one: -

[image]

Comment: [ESP](http://sound.whsites.net/index2.html) really is a great resource. Learnt a lot from his articles and projects.